# Process.Start brings up Publisher could not be verified

Tags: c#

if I Run command like this, it brings up window publisher could not be verified

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("\127.0.0.1\temp\des.exe", " XXXX \127.0.0.1\temp\input.abcd      \127.0.0.1\temp\output.zip");
```

where as if I run like below - no window?? why is this happening? is it because share is not verified or something?

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("c:\temp\des.exe", " XXXX c:\temp\input.abcd      c:\temp\output.zip");
```

Comment: Are you aware that .Net has DES cryptography built-in?  (and that DES is very insecure?)

Comment: I know this des.exe is provided by client so need to use it

Answer (score 2):

It's because youre running executable over network (netbios). It's common windows protection mechanism. No difference that ip is localhost.

You can disable this check in registry:
Save this as file.reg and run

> ```
> Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00
>
>  [HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Download]
>  "CheckExeSignatures"="no"
>  "RunInvalidSignatures"=dword:00000001
> ```

Comment: Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

 [HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Download]
 "CheckExeSignatures"="no"
 "RunInvalidSignatures"=dword:00000001      Adding this to registry should help